# Is there any way to make MAPI emails in Outlook non-modal?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office-2010

In Outlook 2010 64 bit, if I send a new message, that open up a non-modal window. I can return to the main window to do other tasks such as look at a calendar.

However, if I send the mail through [MAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messaging_Application_Programming_Interface) from other office application (e.g. PowerPoint 2010 as shown below) the dialog is modal.

[image: PowerPoint 2010 Save and Send]

Is there a way to make it non-modal? My workaround at the moment is to save the message as a draft and reopen it.